# Best Practice For Error Checking Controls On A Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, error-checking

So I have a form with a variety of different controls (combobox, textboxes, listboxes, etc).

My first thought is to create a If, Else, End If statement. Well while that would work, it could also get pretty long, depending on the amount of controls and combinations.

Validation could include if a listbox is filled, checkbox is checked, etc pertaining to WinForms.

Is there a better solution to check all possiblities than an If statement?

Comment: What kind of error checking?  Could you elaborate on the problem a bit?

Comment: WebForms, WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET MVC? There are probably validating libraries for each.

Comment: Validating if a checkbox is checked, listbos is filled, etc revolving around a WinForm that is being used.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worthwhile to do the error checking as the user fills out the form. This could be implemented with the LostFocus event. Ex:

```
Private Sub btnTest_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles yourbutton.LostFocus
    Dim txt = yourbutton.Text
            If txt = "yourtest" Then
            'do stuff
            EndIf
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As above. It depends on the Validation you are trying to do. Are you validating user input, datatype lenght range, etc. Are you validating business rules. Should such and such a value equal something else. There's all kinds of possibilities.